# Computational Physics or Pure Math Modules for Theoretical Physics

Tags: physics

I'm beginning my university course in Theoretical Physics next week and we have been asked to choose our modules. 
We have compulsory modules in Physics, Vector Algebra and Dynamics. But we also have the choice to study some Pure Math modules (Numbers, Sets and Sequences then Linear Algebra) or Computational Physics modules.
I was wondering which modules would be more beneficial to a theoretical physicist to be. 
Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't [physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) be a better forum for this question? Personal opinion: of the listed options, Linear Algebra seems the most useful, especially given that it's difficult to effectively teach computational methods without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is unfortunately subjective. When I started with down the path of theoretical physics, I would have chosen the computational side - it's certainly useful throughout theoretical physics.

On the other hand, the mathematical side is much more interesting to me. As I had a decently strong background in computer science before my undergraduate degree in theoretical physics, I spent much more time reading mathematics (in my spare time). Interestingly, now Im doing a lot of programming in my PhD (condensed matter), I'm finding the mathematics fundamental to my work. The programming is more of a tool in that point of view.

My personal advice (not that it counts for much) on the matter is to take the mathematics. Spend time learning programming in your spare time. Both are fun to do, but the programming is much easier to pick up online on a casual level IME.

You should also not just focus on physics-related problems in either. Some of the greatest advances in physics come from seemingly unrelated pure mathematics. I know many mathematicians that claim physicists make terrible mathematicians, and I rarely see physicists' code that I don't cringe at.

So learning both, individually and digging your teeth into a variety of challenges in both, may end up helping your physics research greatly later in life. I would choose the mathematics path purely because I think the assistance and challenges from lecturers would be worthwhile.